# Why does auto increment jumps by more than the number of rows inserted (By 3)?

Tags: mysql

I have MariaDB configured frot 3 node Galera Cluster and haproxy and auto increment is going
1,4,7,10,13 etc

Why and how do I fix it?

```
[mysqld]
port = 3307
user                    = mysql
pid-file                = /run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
basedir                 = /usr
datadir                 = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir                  = /tmp
lc-messages-dir         = /usr/share/mysql
lc-messages             = en_US
skip-external-locking


[galera]
max_allowed_packet     = 5G
wsrep_on=ON
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib/galera/libgalera_smm.so
# Specify cluster nodes
wsrep_cluster_address="gcomm://mariadb-1,mariadb-2,mariadb-3"
binlog_format=row
default_storage_engine=InnoDB
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=0
bind-address=0.0.0.0
wsrep_cluster_name="galera_cluster"
wsrep_node_address="mariadb-1"
wsrep_sst_method=rsync

listen galera_cluster
    bind 0.0.0.0:3306
    mode tcp
    option tcpka
    balance source
    server mariadb-1 mariadb-1:3307  check weight 1
    server mariadb-2 mariadb-2:3307  check weight 1
    server mariadb-3 mariadb-3:3307  check weight 1
```

Answer (score 1):

`auto_increment_increment` is necessarily set to the number of nodes in the cluster.  This, together with `auto_increment_offset` prevents `INSERTs` using `AUTO_INCREMENT` from ever colliding.

`AUTO_INCREMENT` guarantees uniqueness, *nothing else*.  You must not depend on anything else.

On another topic:  `max_allowed_packet = 5G` is huge.  It may even cause you trouble.  Please justify such a large vale; we can discuss the consequences and workarounds.

Comment: The max value for `max_allowed_packet` is 1G.

Comment: I have changed it to add still the same `max_allowed_packet     = 1G` `auto_increment_increment = 3` and `auto_increment_offse = 1`

Comment: Please do not try to change `auto_increment_*`; Galera needs to be in control of those two settings.  Anyway, the "offset" needs to be different in each node.

Comment: If I stop two servers it work correct. Does HaProxy setup correct?

Comment: If you stop two servers, you have no HA.  Also, that one node will think that there might be a "split-brain" and it will refuse to accept writes.

Comment: _Please_ study the principles of Galera.  I have given you a much-simplified summary of it, but you seem to be confused on some of the details.